# Find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(-2\sqrt{3}+i)^n=2^{n-1}(1-i\sqrt{3})$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I was requested to find all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(-2\sqrt{3}+i)^n=2^{n-1}(1-i\sqrt{3})$. My approach was

$$(-2\sqrt{3}+i)^n=2^{n-1}(1-i\sqrt{3})$$

$$\implies 2^n(-\sqrt{3}+i)^n= \frac{2^n(1-i\sqrt{3})}{2}$$

$$\implies (-\sqrt{3}+i)^n = \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

However, I was unable to proceed from here. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first $\Rightarrow$ is wrong. Have you tried in polar coordinates?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the equation correctly?  Taking the absolute value of both sides gives $\sqrt{13}^n = 2^n$, which is impossible (unless $n=0$, but then the phase angles don't match up).

Comment: Correction: $\implies 2^n(-\sqrt{3}+\frac i2)^n= \frac{2^n(1-i\sqrt{3})}{2}\implies (-\sqrt{3}+\frac i2)^n = \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $(-2\sqrt{3}+i)^n=2^{n-1}(1-i\sqrt{3})$, then_
$$(-2\sqrt{3}+i)^n=2^{n-1}(1-i\sqrt{3})$$

$$\implies 2(-\sqrt{3}+i)^n= 2^n(1-i\sqrt{3})$$

$$\implies (\frac{-\sqrt{3}+i}{2})^n = \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Take $z=\frac{-\sqrt{3}+i}{2}$. Then $\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}=i\bar{z}$
So we have the complex equation
$$z^n=i\bar{z}$$
Since $\vert z\vert =1$, we have $z^{n+1}=i$. Can you conclude from here?

**Edit**: Suppose there exist some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such the inequality holds. Applying the modulus both sides we Will get that $\sqrt{13}^n=2^n$, which is clearly impossible

Comment: Small typo I think: after your first $\Rightarrow$ there should be a $2$ in front of $\sqrt{3}$ within the parenthesis on the LHS

Answer (score 0):

Use the exponential form:
$$-2\sqrt{3}+i=\sqrt{13}e^{i\cdot \theta }$$
Where:
$$\theta=\arctan\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)+\pi$$

Also:

$$1-\sqrt{3}i=2e^{i\cdot \phi}$$

Where:
$$\phi=\arctan(-\sqrt{3})$$

We have:

$$13^{\frac{n}{2}}\cdot e^{i\cdot n \cdot\theta} = 2^{n-1}\cdot \sqrt{5}\cdot e^{i\cdot \phi}$$

Real and immagine parts must be equal. Can you conclude it now?